# How to call add a second method on a .ashx file

Tags: javascript, c#, ashx

I have a method to play a language audio, but at the moment this method is only playing one language. 
I want to call another method which will do the same function but for another language as opposed to a different file all together.

My file:

```
public class AudioHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        using (The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_FactoryDBContext())
        {
    bytes = db.Words.FirstOrDefault(word => word.wordID == id).engAudio; // here will be the change in the second method .afrAudio

                context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                context.Response.Flush();
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

}

How do i call the second method?

this is how i am calling this handler:

```
audio.src = "/AudioHandler.ashx?id=" + id;
```

How would this differ when there is a second method and what will it look like

Thanks

Comment: You need to make the first call asynchronously so it returns immediately, then make other calls.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299194/making-asynchronous-calls-form-generic-handler-ashx